# How to run node on server

Tags: node.js

i am new in node.js and i want to create chat system so anybody help me that how can i run my codes on local and on server

Server - (app.js):

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function () { });
  socket.on('disconnect', function () { });
});
```

Client - (index.html):

```
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost/');
  socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.send('hi');

    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
      // my msg
    });
  });
</script>
```

what is server (app.js) and how can i run this on my server and how can i call this function to client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1. Install node.

Download package from https://nodejs.org/en/, then you got npm and node file.

Create soft link to /usr/local/ for npm and node file.

Step 2. Crate your app.js, and typing:

```
node app.js
```

then, your code is running. And you can test in your frontend.
If you wanna your code running background, you can use pm2.

```
npm install -g pm2
```

After that, `pm2 start app.js`. Your code is running background.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_hello_world.htm
You need node installed on your server as a prerequisite.

Once you have nodejs installed, the app can be executed as `node app.js`

Comment: can you please tell me how to setup node on my own server ?

Comment: i already do this now i have confusion that how can run code on my server

Comment: my question is that do i need to create a file and write code which handle server and other one who handles client ?

Comment: Unable to understand your question. I guess it will be better if you follow the tutorial mentioned above. You’ll get a good understanding of the technology stack.